# react-google-calendar-api sign-in and sign-out callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate the libraries to interface with google calendar into a small test application. I configured everything correctly and I can log in and out, what I can't do is intercept the related events, i.e. login successful or login canceled.

I'm using the [react-google-calendar-api](https://github.com/Kubessandra/react-google-calendar-api) libraries, but I haven't found how to configure any callbacks available.

```
const GoogleCalendarTestButton = (props) => {

  const onLoginClick = (e) => {
    apiCalendar.handleAuthClick();
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={onLoginClick}
      >login</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```